# File-based dynamically-allocated hard-disk on Linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, virtualbox, vhd

I can create a regular file on an existing file-system (say, ext4), make it into a block device (via `losetup`), and format it with an ext4 file-system of its own.

But the above hard-disk is of a fixed size.

**Question:**

1. `VirtualBox` allows you to create VDI, VMDK, and VHD types of hard-disks that can be either fixed- or dynamically-sized. **Is there any way to** make a file-based dynamically-sized hard-disk for use by a Linux host OS?
2. **Is it possible to** employ any of these three types of file-based, dynamically-sized hard-disks outside of `VirtualBox`, on a Linux host OS?

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: There are tools to resize the partitions but I don't get how you plan to leave parts of the hard drive unallocated.  This makes much more sense on a VM.

Comment: What does "employ" mean in this context?

Comment: @Deltik By "employ" I mean, using any of those file-based hard-disk formats on the host OS without VirtualBox. Eg, if I mount this file-based hdisk on my host OS, and if a host program (eg, `cat`) writes to a file sitting in this hdisk, then this hdd should automatically expand if needed.

Comment: If you mean writing to a mount of a partition in a raw image and the raw image was originally created sparsely, then yes, it will expand as data is written to the raw image.

Comment: @Deltik Great! Then, is using `qemu-img` necessary? I think, the key point in your answer is **sparse files**, which I did not know ext4 supported. I could create a sparse file, and use `losetup` and `mke2fs`, right?

Comment: Yes, @Harry.  The second part of my answer was my guess as to what you meant by "employ".  The key is indeed **sparse files**, and you are right about creating a filesystem on the loopback device of the sparse file.

Comment: You made my day, comrade!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Yes, if your filesystem supports sparse files.  (ext4 supports sparse files.)

   Here's how you create a `64GiB` raw image `disk.img` that initially takes up almost no space:

   ```
   truncate -s 64G disk.img
   ```
2. You can now use the `disk.img` as a loopback block device, and it will expand as you write to it.

---

#### Bonus Features

If you want to convert a disk image `disk.img` to another format, like to a physical disk `/dev/sdb`, use `qemu-img`:

```
qemu-img convert -O raw disk.img /dev/sdb
```

This is useful if you want to convert VDI, VMDK, VHD, or other container formats into RAW so that you can manipulate the output image using built-in tools like `losetup`/`kpartx`.

It doesn't matter what format the source image is.  `qemu-img` can work with more than VDI, VMDK, VHD, and raw images.  To see a list of supported images, run this command:

```
    root@node51 [~]# qemu-img --help | grep 'Supported formats:'
    Supported formats: bochs vvfat rbd vpc parallels tftp ftp ftps raw https qcow http dmg qcow2 quorum null-aio cloop vdi null-co vhdx blkverify file vmdk host_cdrom blkdebug host_device sheepdog iscsi qed nbd
```

Comment: +1 for `truncate`. The name of the command doesn't do full justice to it as it can expand the thing as well, and that too, sparsely!

Comment: Not a dynamic. read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3530654/8747573

Comment: @ajcg: This answer does create a dynamically growing disk image from a regular file.  Perhaps you are confusing "dynamically allocated" with "preallocated"?

Comment: "So, when doing this, you will be deferring physical allocation until the file is accessed" From “Dan McAllister” on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257844/quickly-create-a-large-file-on-a-linux-system

Comment: With truncate we can create a 100 GB disk quickly without taking up space. But when accessing the virtual disk image (to format it, in ntfs, ext4, etc, and save some files) it automatically expands to 100 GB (I did these tests myself). truncate or dd neither create dynamic disks. Additionally, truncate is not reliable. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8706714/8747573

Comment: @ajcg: A "dynamic disk" as used in this question means a disk image that grows as stuff is written into it. That's exactly what happens with `truncate -s` on a file system that supports sparse files, which I made clear at the beginning of my answer. It appears that you believe that a dynamic disk is preallocated/initialized to take up all the space from the beginning. This is _not_ what a dynamic disk is.

Comment: I know what a dynamic disk is. Virtualbox works with dynamic disks (vdi). And what this answer claims is wrong and does not create a dynamic disk. I already gave the query references on what I say (I am not the only one saying it and you are the only one claiming such a thing)

Comment: anyway, whoever asked the question, has already selected the answer. He already has his solution and is happy with it. I say that answer is incorrect, but who am I to contradict him and take away his happiness, so case closed.

Comment: @ajcg: If this answer is wrong, please feel free to contribute an answer of your own. So far, you have presented a differing opinion but no solution.

Comment: I may be wrong to say this (but I don't think so). The question has no solution. The limitation is the .img format which is not dynamic. that works with other image formats

Comment: Again, the sparse file disk image is indeed dynamically sized. You can even shrink it again after files are deleted off of compatible file systems in the disk image. [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20131205025456/https://dustymabe.com/2013/06/11/recover-space-from-vm-disk-images-by-using-discardfstrim/) is a demo showing that a 30GiB sparse file disk image taking up only the amount of used space inside the image's file system. This information is outside the scope of the question, however.

Comment: Why do you validate what I am say?. Create a 10GB `truncate` image. Mount it in `/dev/loopXX`. Format it (ntfs, ext4, whatever you want), save a file inside 1mb. umount `/dev/loopXX`. Copy the image to another drive. You will see what happens. when you do that you will copy a real 10GB file to another drive. Not a 100mb file or similar. that is not dynamic. don't show examples. do it yourself

Comment: @ajcg: [I did exactly what you said](https://pastebin.com/zExzTbRU), and the sparse file still takes up only as much disk space as there are contents in it.  Note that the difference of size (1.3MiB vs. 5.3MiB) is because I have compression on the source ZFS file system, which is not available on the tmpfs.  The file remains sparse.  There is no "gotcha" here.  The sparse disk image is indeed dynamic as desired by the question.